# My discord bot gives me AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'")

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a discord bot that is written in python. The bot is supposed give roles and remove roles on a emoji reaction. But today I got this error when I tried to get a role  AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'")  and this error when I tried to remove the role AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'").

The main file:

````
from discord import utils
 
import config
 
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
            
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
            
            if payload.message_id != 669082231955783707:
                print('[Error] Wrong message id {0.display_name}'.format(member))
                return

            if (len([i for i in member.roles if i.id in config.ROLES.values()]) < config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))
        
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
       
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
 
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))
 
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
 
# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using await [Guild.fetch_member(id)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch%20member#discord.Guild.fetch_member) or [Guild.get_member(id)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get%20member#discord.Guild.fetch_user) in order to receive your member object. From there you should be able to add and remove roles as you like.

You're encountering an issue where `utils.get` isn't returning a member object.
You may also want to try enabling `Server Members Intent` in the discord developer portal and adding the intent when initializing your Client object.

Comment: I have been trying to enable the intents by doing so 

´´´
import discord
from discord import utils
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext import commands 

import config

intents = Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents = intents´´´
 
but it did not make any sense. What is wrong?

Comment: `import discord` --> `intents = discord.Intents.default()` --> `intents.members = True` --> `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)` -- You should be submitting your intents when initializing your client/bot object.